# Prevent Norton from deleting downloaded files

Tags: anti-virus, norton-internet-security

I am trying to download a file to a Windows 10 machine, but Norton keeps on deleting it!  See first screen shot.

I've read articles about creating an "excluded folder" or sending Norton confirmation that it was a false positive, and I've gone through all the tabs on the second screenshot, but there appears to be no way to do so.

How do I prevent Norton from deleting a downloaded file which it incorrectly thinks is a threat?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why not just disable Norton until after you're done downloading the file in question?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007  How can one disable Norton?  I've looked for options.  I've logged on as Admin and accessed services, but "stop" is greyed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a folder which you don't wish Norton to scan.  I called mine "Downloads - No Norton Scan".
2. Log onto Windows as Admin.  **It will not work if you are logged on as a normal user, and try to just run Norton as admin, and Norton will not inform you why it isn't working.**
3. Open up Norton.  Go to Antivirus => Scans and Risk =>Exclusions/Low Risk => Items to Exclude from Auto-Protect, Sonar, and Download Intelligence Detection, and add the folder to it.  If desired, also add the folder to "Items to Exclude from Scans" should you wish to keep Norton false-positive files (my desire was just one-time installation of software so I did not do so).
4. Download the file to this folder.